# Need to break out of iframe and change top state

Tags: javascript, iframe, angular-ui-router

After making a payment within an iFrame, After the payment I need to break out the iFrame and change state of the top page which is a SPA.
I am able to break out using the following javascript snippet

```
if( self == top ) {
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ; 
} else {
  top.location = self.location ;
}
```

but then I get a blank page which is not part of my SPA.
Please adice

Comment: yes, your SPA-tab is redirected to the URL of the iframe, which I'd guess is the reason for the blank page. *Don't (try to) manipulate foreign windows/frames.* Use the [messaging system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) instead to communicate between the two frames. But that means that the iframe can only send a message to the SPA, like an event, and the SPA has to await the message and change its own state according to the message.

Comment: Thanks for the good advise.
I implemented it and it works flowlessly